# Docusign add note in a template and prefill it before sending the envelope

Tags: docusignapi

i need to enter the signer address in a template docusign as a note field and prefill it when creating the envelope and before sending it. Thanks for help.

there is my php code:

```
$envelope_definition = new EnvelopeDefinition([
    'status' => 'sent', 'template_id' => $this->template_id
]);
# Create the template role elements to connect the signer and cc recipients
# to the template

$signer = new TemplateRole([
    'email'             => $args['signer_email'],
    'name'              => $args['signer_name'],
    'role_name'         => 'signer'
]);
```

$address_note = new Note(['selected' => 'true', 'tab_label' => 'signer_address', 'value' => $args['signer_address']]);
$signer->setTabs(new Tabs([$address_note]));
$envelope_definition->setTemplateRoles([$signer]);

and there is the configuration of note field in the dashboard docusign: note field

But the problem is when signing the document i can't see the signer address

When i try to find the tabs in the apropriate template using this php code :

```
# create the envelope definition with the template_id
    $envelope_definition = new EnvelopeDefinition([
        'status' => 'sent', 'template_id' => $this->template_id
    ]);
    # Create the template role elements to connect the signer and cc recipients
    # to the template

    $signer = new TemplateRole([
        'email'             => $args['signer_email'],
        'name'              => $args['signer_name'],
        'role_name'         => 'signer'
    ]);

    dd($signer->getTabs());
```

i got null as result.

Comment: Answered below. If it helps you out, be sure to upvote and accept. Thanks! –

Answer (score 0):

Before you make your request, check to ensure that your template contains the appropriate note field that you want to prepopulate. You can do so by making a GET request to /templates.

```
GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{account_ID}/templates/{template_ID}?include=recipients,tabs
```

Now, To prepopulate a note field with the physical mailing address for a particular recipient, you can make a POST request to /envelopes. You will find the tabLabel from the previous step.

```
{
    "status": "sent",
    "templateId": "00df08bf-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ecaa2360c121",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "name": "ABC",
            "roleName": "signer",
            "routingOrder": "1",
            "tabs": {
                "noteTabs": [
                    {
                        "selected": "true",
                        "tabLabel": "userAddress",
                        "value": "theUsersAddressGoesHere"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "email": "test2@test.com",
            "name": "EFG",
            "roleName": "cc",
            "routingOrder": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you are unable to see the value of the note field when signing, you may need to change the size of the bounding box. You can do this either by editing the template in the UI or adding X/Y properties to your request.

Comment: I changed the width and the height of the appropriate note field, it appears when signing the document but its empty .

Comment: Do you see the note icon when signing? Or nothing entirely?

Comment: For the proper SDK syntax, take a look at this code example. I think you may be attaching your note tab to recipient incorrectly. https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/set-template-tab-values

Comment: Yes i can see the note icon but its empty .

Comment: Try logging the value of $args['signer_address']]. Are you seeing the address as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, i resolve the issue, the solution is :

```
    $envelope_definition = new EnvelopeDefinition([
        'status' => 'sent', 'template_id' => $this->template_id
    ]);

    $address_note = new Note(['selected' => "true", 'tab_label' => 'signer_address', 'value' => $args['signer_address']]);
    $tabs = new Tabs(['note_tabs' => [$address_note]]);
    $signer = new TemplateRole([
        'email'             => $args['signer_email'],
        'name'              => $args['signer_name'],
        'role_name'         => 'signer',
        'tabs'              => $tabs
    ]);
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you would, please clean up your question by copying your other answer below (since it is not an answer) and pasting it into the body of your original question.